# How to render the data from .mvt or .vector.pbf file from scratch?

Tags: rendering, protocol-buffers, mapbox, vector-tiles

I signed up for the Mapbox vector tiles service and I've noticed that they provide map data in .mvt and .vector.pbf formats.

I tried to open these files with normal text editor and read them with the intention to see the structure and find a way to draw some parts of a map with javascript/html drawing functions. However , the files data seems unreadable for me.

How can I parse these files , and how can I draw simple map with their content ? (I read the .MVT specs here https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification , but I couldn't find any solution)

Note that I want to do it from scratch , without using mapbox-js or Leaflet libraries.

Comment: The specs you've linked have all the necessary information to implement a parser. That's what specs are meant for. If you can't handle it better go for a existent solution, mapbox-gl-js or MapBox Vector Tile plugin for Leaflet. Or at least, take a look at the source code of those implementations and see how they do it.

Comment: I was hoping to get references to some papers/blog posts/books with POC's and some step by step explanations. However, if there aren't any the other option is "debugging" the existing open source libs. The downside of this is that there are years of development which added a lot of abstraction which is making it a little hard to reveal the basic implementation.